# Strictly positive definite autocovariance function of fGn

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, matrices

Hi,

let $\gamma(k) = 1/2 (|k+1|^{2H} + |k-1|^{2H}-2|k|^{2H}),k\in\mathbb{Z},$ be autocovariance function of fractional Gaussian noise where $H\in(0,1)$ is parameter.

I want to show that $\gamma$ is strictly positive definite function, i. e., for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the matrix $\Gamma = (\gamma(i-j))_{i,j=1}^n$ is (strictly) positive definite.

I tried to do that by using tools of linear algebra, unfortunately I wasn't successful. I spent some time googling and found that Bochner's theorem [1] might help me. I don't understand how and I wasn't able to find an explanation of the application either.

Is it possible to show it using Bochner's theorem? Or is it possible to do it in a different way?

Thank you very much!

Tomas

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem#Applications

Comment: are you sure this function is even positive (semi)definite as written?

Comment: i'm asking because unless i'm mistaken, take $H=0.25$ and try a 3x3 matrix; you'll get a counterexample....

Comment: $\gamma$ is autocovariance function of fractional Gaussian noise, so it must be positive definite function. And based od my computation, 3x3 matrix for $H=0.25$ is positive definite matrix.

Comment: Is it: $(1/2)*$something or is it: $1/(2*(...))$? Maybe that's the problem here in my parsing of your question...

Comment: It is (1/2) * (something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Mathematica, the inverse Fourier transform of your function $\gamma(x)$ is

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sec \left(\frac{\pi  h}{2}\right) (\cos (t)-1) |t|^{-h-1}}{\Gamma (-h)}
\end{equation*}

But for $0 < h < 1$, $\sec(\pi h/2) / \Gamma(-h)$ is negative, also $\cos(t)-1 \le 0$, so overall the IFT is nonnegative. Thus, $k(x,y) := \gamma(x-y)$ is a positive definite function. For strict positive definiteness some more work might be needed.

Comment: I have found stronger version of Bochner theorem here http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/603_ch2.pdf. Inverse Fourier transform, that you have computed, is non-negative and its support is whole real line. Using theorem 2.3.1 from link above we can proof strict positive definitness of $\gamma(x)$.

Comment: @Tomas: true! I had forgotten about this result, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested to [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2047839) (and the references therein).